# Why JPA generate Entities from Tables orders fields alphabetically?

Tags: eclipse, jpa, entity, dali

When generating JPA Entities in Eclipse using JPA Tools, the fields are ordered alphabetically instead of the order defined in the Tables.

**My DB**

[image]

**JPA Generated Entity**

[image]

Any idea how to switch this off?
The problem is if I set ddl-auto, then the columns in the DB Table are generated in the Entity order which makes it very confusing when browsing the data using the DB.